# Simple Session Management Across Multiple Application Servers

Tags: authentication, session-management, oauth, authorization, iphone

How should I handle authentication for a simple iPhone chat app?

### Backend

I'm building the backend using two application servers:

1. Sinatra REST Server

   It lists users & old messages.
2. Node.js WebSocket Server

   It sends & receives new messages.

### Proposal

1. When a user signs up or logs in, the REST server returns an access token.
2. The iPhone app [passes that access token to the WebSocket server on connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461534/websocket-send-extra-information-on-connection).
3. The WebSocket server derives the user ID from the access token.

### Thoughts

I want to do the least amount of work that will make the app reasonably secure.

1. iPhone App Authentication: Store a shared `cleint_secret` on the iPhone app using [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html). Pass the `client_secret` to the REST server for the sign-up & log-in requests. This allows the REST server to verify all requests are coming from the iPhone app and thus prevent attackers from signing up or logging in from other clients. [Facebook authenticates iOS apps](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51385/facebook-ios-sdk-authentication) by only using app & bundle IDs. That would be cool because then I wouldn't need create a `client_secret`, but I'm not sure how they do it.
2. Access Token Generation: It'd be cool if the user ID was somehow encrypted in the access token with a secret shared between the REST & WebSocket servers. Then, the WebSocket server could use the shared secret to verify the access token and extract the user ID from it. Is that possible? If so, what is a secure algorithm to achieve that? I think I can do this with [HMAC](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/how-when-do-i-use-hmac), where the message is the user ID. If so, which HMAC algorithm should I use? Here are some of my recent thoughts on [how to generate an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689764/242933). Something like HMAC would be cool because then I wouldn't need to store access tokens for every user ID, e.g., in a Redis database. Although, maybe that's what I should do. Because now that I think about it, if I use something like HMAC, and a user's access token is stolen, then how would I reset that access token without reseting all of them?